# How does code in the boost::log tutorial work?

Tags: c++, boost-log

I haven't worked with C++ for some time, and I feel a little lost in the syntax. Could someone explain me the following lines from the `boost::log` library tutorial?

```
logging::core::get()->set_filter
(
    logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
);
```

As far as I can see it's the function `set_filter()` call, but it takes a `filter` object:

```
BOOST_LOG_API void set_filter(filter const& filter)
```

and the expression:

```
logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
```

returns bool? Is `operator >=` overloaded here? I've tried to figure it out through looking for definitions and macros but I can't see any operator overloading. It looks illogical to me. What does it do? How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info` returns a function object.

The function object does the comparison.

It is done by Boost.Phoenix library.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I've read a little about a Boost.Phoenix library and I think I'm getting the general idea of that code, although I'm far from understanding the way library works.